# How to parse a string for an integer matrix in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, parsing, nsmutablearray

Can someone help me extracting a 2D matrix of integers from a string like the one below in Objective C?

1  1  0  0 -1

-1  0  1  1  0

0 -1  0  1  0

0  0 -1 -1  1

Comment: Are there line terminators in the string?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use an NSScanner object.  See the [Strings Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC) for further info.